# permutation and f(n) challenge

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, permutations, recurrence-relations, contest-math

Suppose $f(n)$ be the number of permutation from set ${1,2,..,n}$ such
that for each $ 1 \leq i \leq n$ we have: $ | \pi(i)-i| \leq 1 $.
meaning of $ \pi(i)$ is an elements whose in place $i$ of permutation.
for example in permutation $<2,3,1>$, $ \pi(1)=2$.

> > how we reach to $f(10)= 89$

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Perhaps you could show an attempt and clarify your writing?

Comment: Do you mean $1 \le i \le \color{red}{n}$ and $|\pi(i) - \color{red}{i}| \le 1$?

Comment: dear @achillehui i edit it

Comment: @Jinous, If that is the case, then $f(10)$ should be 89.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How did you get $f(10)=4$? For $f(2n)$, there are at least $2^n$ permutations, since you can swap every pair of neighbors in $123\cdots n$.

This is induction. For $n=1$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$. Notice that $f(n+1)=f(n)+f(n-1)$, accounting for: if $\pi(n+1)=n+1$, there are $f(n)$ many permutations, if $\pi(n+1)=n$, then $\pi(n)=n+1$, and there are $f(n-2)$ such permutations. There are no other options since the index of $n+1$ cannot be less than $n$.

This is the Fibonacci recurrence, so $f(n)=F_{n+1}$, where $F_n$ is the $n$'th Fibonacci number. Then as you point out, $f(10)=89$.

Comment: you means f(10)=89 ?

Comment: i couldent underestand you first two lines

Comment: @Jinous, the first two lines implies $f(10) \ge 2^5 = 32$. This is because you can break $1,2,\ldots,10$ into 5 groups $1,2; 3,4; \ldots ; 9,10$ and there are $2^5$ ways to permute elements within each group and all of them meet you criterion.